# Is there a connection between the adjoint matrix and the adjoint of the Jordan matrix?

Tags: matrices, jordan-normal-form

I saw a solution of an olympiad problem that I didn't understand and I'm confused if it's actually correct. The problem is:

Let $n\in\mathbb{Z}_{\geq2}$ and $A,B\in M_n(\mathbb{C})$ so that there exists an idempotent matrix $C\in M_n(\mathbb{C})$ such that C*$=AB-BA$. Prove that $AB-BA=O_n$. (C* is the adjoint/reciprocal of the matrix, not the conjugate transpose).

The solution begins by considering the Jordan form of C, $C=S^{-1}JS$, where J is a diagonal matrix with $0$'s or $1$'s on the diagonal(because C is idempotent). If there is only $1$'s on the diagonal, $C=I_n$ and there is a contradiction taking the trace in the statement.

Here comes the part I don't understand. It says that if J has one $0$ on the diagonal, its adjoint has one $1$ on the diagonal and the rest are $0$'s, resulting in it having trace $1$ in contradiction with C*$=AB-BA$, and that if it has more than one zero on the diagonal, its adjoint is $O_n$, which supposedly gives the conclusion. I don't get what the connection between J* and C* is that makes us able to conclude what the solution says.

Comment: To illustrate, if $D=\operatorname{diag}(d_1,d_2,d_3)$, then $\operatorname{adj}(D)=\operatorname{diag}(d_2d_3,\,d_1d_3,\,d_1d_2)$. Therefore, when $d_1=0$ and $d_2=d_3=1$, we have $\operatorname{adj}(D)=\operatorname{diag}(1,0,0)$.

Comment: In general, if $D=\operatorname{diag}(d_1,d_2,\ldots,d_n)$, then
$$
\operatorname{adj}(D)=\operatorname{diag}\left(\prod_{i\ne1}d_i,\,\prod_{i\ne2}d_i,\,\ldots,\,\prod_{i\ne n}d_i\right).
$$

Comment: Yes, I get that part, but what correlation is there between J* and C*. I mean the solution finds the form of J*, but how does that help us directly? I don't think that C*=$S^{-1}$J*$S$ is always true, so from where does the solution conclude things about AB-BA?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using $\operatorname{adj}(XY)=\operatorname{adj}(Y)\operatorname{adj}(X)$, we get
\begin{aligned}
\operatorname{adj}(S^{-1}JS)
&=\operatorname{adj}(S)\operatorname{adj}(J)\operatorname{adj}(S^{-1})\\
&=\left(\det(S)\frac{\operatorname{adj}(S)}{\det(S)}\right)\operatorname{adj}(J)\left(\det(S^{-1})\frac{\operatorname{adj}(S^{-1})}{\det(S^{-1}}\right)\\
&=\det(S)\det(S^{-1})\left(S^{-1}\operatorname{adj}(J)S\right)\\
&=S^{-1}\operatorname{adj}(J)S.
\end{aligned}
Alternatively, recall that if $p$ is the characteristic polynomial of a linear operator $A$ defined on an $n$-dimensional vector space, then $\operatorname{adj}(A)=q(A)$ where $q$ is the polynomial defined by $q(x)=(-1)^{n-1}\frac{p(x)-p(0)}{x-0}$. Now let $p$ be the common characteristic polynomial of $J$ and $S^{-1}JS$. Then
$$
\operatorname{adj}(S^{-1}JS)
=q(S^{-1}JS)
=S^{-1}q(J)S
=S^{-1}\operatorname{adj}(J)S.
$$